# TSQL - Extract LastName and first initial of FirstName from FullName field that may or may not have a title

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a requirement to extract from a full name column the last name and the first initial of the first name regardless if they have a title or not. Here are some samples of the data:

FullName Examples:

- ALLAN MD,BEER
- SIG DO,JEFFREY CAR
- Passion, Fruit

Expected Output:

- ALLAN_B
- SIG_J
- Passion_F

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database. Including a _question_ is also suggested.

Answer (score 2):

So, you want everything before the first space/comma and then the first non-space character after the first comma.  If so:

```
select (left(fullname, patindex('%[, ]%', fullname) - 1) + '_' +
        left(ltrim(stuff(fullname, 1, charindex(',', fullname), '')), 1)
       )
```